# getting null object reference when trying to initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider

Tags: amazon-s3, nullpointerexception, initialization, sharedpreferences

i am using amazon to store my app picture but when i try to initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider i get an exception. here is the initialization

the log is about sharedpref null pointer exception

```
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        this,
        "someidentity", // Identity pool ID
        Regions.US_EAST_2 // Region
);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that when i intialized the:

```
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
```

i did it with "credentialsProvider" function whice is what i posted above
to solve this i just called the static credentialProvider that amazon provide "sCredProvider" in the Util Class

so the function looks like this:

```
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(sCredProvider);
```

which inherit from the "UtilAWS3" Class

hope this helps anyone who gets this weird problem :)